# Power BI is unable to parse OData response result from SAP Commerce

Tags: powerbi, odata, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, sap-bw

I am trying to connect from Power BI Desktop to SAP Commerce, through an OData interface that exposes orders:

https://my-sap-commerce.com/odata2webservices/oDataTest/Orders

By default, the query retrieves 10 records but I get the following error on the eleventh row:

> ```
> DataSource.Error. Unable to parse OData response result. Error: A type named 'HybrisCommerceOData.Order' 
> could not be resolved by the model.
> When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.
>            Detalles:
>            DataSourceKind=OData
>            DataSourcePath=https://my-sap-commerce.com/odata2webservices/oDataTest/Orders
> ```

Is it possible to define this type (or any other related to SAP Commerce) in Power BI Desktop or is it necessary any external driver which knows about these types?

BTW, I have followed the instructions in [Connecting SAP Data Warehouse Cloud OData API with PowerBI via a Blank Query](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/09/23/connecting-sap-data-warehouse-cloud-odata-api-with-powerbi-via-a-blank-query-2/) to configure Power BI Desktop.

Thanks in advance.